# Accessing and listing attributes in a Python class

Tags: python, class, attributes, listings

I have created a class inside a class structure in Python. At the end, I try to retrieve a list of one of its attributes (`price`) to `sum` all the values and do math operations with it.

It keeps telling me that neither my class `TOOLBOX` or my class `DATA` has the attribute `Price`. How could I solve this?

My code looks like this:

```
class DATA:
    def __init__(self, Identifier, Price, Date, Postcode, Type, Age, Tenure, Primary, Secondary, Street, Locality, Town, District, County, Status):
        self.Identifier = Identifier
        self.Price = Price
        self.Date = Date
        self.Postcode = Postcode
        self.Type = Type
        self.Age = Age
        self.Tenure = Tenure
        self.Primary = Primary
        self.Secondary = Secondary
        self.Street = Street
        self.Locality = Locality
        self.Town = Town
        self.District = District
        self.County = County
        self.Status = Status

class TOOLBOX(object):

    def __init__ (self):
        self.alldata = []

    def add_data(self, Identifier, Price, Date, Postcode, Type, Time, Tenure, Primary, Secondary, Street, Locality, Town, District, County, Status):
        self.alldata.append(DATA(Identifier, Price, Date, Postcode, Type, Time, Tenure, Primary, Secondary, Street, Locality, Town, District, County, Status))

    def get_prize(self) :
        price=[]
        for line in self.alldata:
                price.append(self.alldata.Price)
        print price

    def summation(self):
        return sum(self.alldata.Price)



csv_ff = csv.reader(open("FINAL.csv",'rU'))
l=len(list(csv.reader(open("FINAL.csv",'rU'))))

dd = TOOLBOX()

for line in csv_ff:
    if len(line)==15:

        Identifier=line[0]
        Price=int(line[1])
        Date=line[2]
        Postcode=line[3]
        Type=line[4]
        Age=line[5]
        Tenure=line[6]
        Primary=line[7]
        Secondary=line[8]
        Street=line[9]
        Locality=line[10]
        Town=line[11]
        District=line[12]
        County=line[13]
        Status=line[14]

        dd.add_data(Identifier, Price, Date, Postcode, Type, Age, Tenure, Primary, Secondary, Street, Locality, Town, District, County, Status)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `price.append(line.Price)`?

Answer (score 1):

`Price` is an attibute of the `DATA` instances stored in the the `self.alldata` list. Hence you need to iterate over the `self.alldata` list and grab the `Price` attribute like so:

```
def get_prices(self) :
    prices=[]
    for line in self.alldata:
         price.append(line.Price)
    return prices
```

Notes:

1. I renamed the method from `get_prize` to `get_prices`
2. `get_prices()` now *returns* the list of prices instead of just
   printing them.
3. If `get_prices()` is to print the list of prices it would be better
   named `display_prices()` or similar - `get_prize()` suggests that
   the method returns a value.

Then your summation method can get the list of prices by calling `get_prices()` and sum them:

```
def summation(self):
    return sum(self.get_prices())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the attribute using you allData list:

```
self.alldata.Price # incorrect 

self.Price # correct
```

`self.Price` is the attribute in of the `DATA` class , `self.alldata` is a list containing DATA instances, you would need to iterate over the list and call something like `ele.Price` to access the attribute where ele is `for ele in self.alldata`:....

You are basically trying to do `[].Price` on the list, a list certainly does not have a Price method so this is going to fail.

```
    def get_prize(self) :
        price = []
        for line in self.alldata: # stores instances of DATA
              price.append(line.Price) # access attribute using the instance
        print price

def summation(self):
    return sum(inst.Price for inst in self.alldata) # again access using instance
```

If you change the `get_prize` method to return a list of prices:

```
     def get_prize(self) :
            price = []
            for line in self.alldata: # stores instances of DATA
                  price.append(line.Price) # access attribute using the instamce
            return  price
```

We can simply use that method to sum:

```
    def summation(self):
        return sum(self.get_prize())
```

We can also return a  list comprehension in `get_prize` which is a bit more concise and using a variable that is more descriptive of what each element is:

```
def get_prize(self) :
    return  [inst.Price for inst  in self.alldata]
```

On a side note use lowercase and underscores for attributes etc..  `self.price, identifier self.all_data`...

Comment: Thanks SO much to both of you. I had been stuck on that one for almost a whole day, and it now works :). I´ve only just started programming, and this might be a bit of a conceptual flaw, but why doesnt my DATA class show all the attributes I´ve defined when i do dir(DATA) ?. I just get this:
>>> dir(DATA)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__']

Comment: do you mean `dr = DATA(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,11,1,1,1,1)print(dir(dr))`? You need to create an instance first

Answer (score 0):

You class `DATA` does have the attribute - what does not have the Price attribute is the attr. `alldata` from `TOOLBOX` .It is just a list.

While it would be possible, easy, and fun in Python to build a sequence object that could behave in this "jQueriest" way - that is: upon wanting an attribute from the sequence, retrieve a sequence of that attributes for all objects in the sequence, that is not the default behavior of the language  - 
Without specialized classes, doing `toolbox_object.alldata.Price` tries to retrieve the `Price` attribute of `alldata`.

To retrieve a sequence of all prices (as a generator expression), you should write:

```
(elem.Price for elem in toolbox_object.alldata)
```

Therefore, your line that goes:

```
def summation(self):
    return sum(self.alldata.Price)
```

You should have:

```
def summation(self):
    return sum(element.Price for element in self.alldata)
```

(by the way, your  `DATA` class  should also inherit from "object")

Now, for fun, if you want the jQuery-like attribute retrieval, you can create a derived from Python's lists with just an extra `__getattr__` method  - that should work  (the really "by the book", "product ready" thing could be implemented with Abstract Base Classes, and so on - but this just works):

```
class JQList(list):
     def __getattr__(self, attr):
          return [getattr(element, attr) for element in self]

>>> import random
>>> 
>>> b = JQList()
>>> b = JQList(random.randint(0,10) + random.randint(0,10) * 1j for i in range(10) )
>>> b
[(5+7j), (3+4j), 3j, (4+9j), (1+9j), (2+3j), (1+0j), (10+4j), 9j, (9+10j)]
>>> b.real
[5.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 10.0, 0.0, 9.0]
>>> b.imag
[7.0, 4.0, 3.0, 9.0, 9.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4.0, 9.0, 10.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**More Hints** to this code - (for the answer to your problem, check my other answer)

Python is a Language that allows one to really write short, and readable code - 
In this small example, you are repeating the name of 15 attributes 7 times over --- that is a lot of attribute name typing :-)

So, without any changes to your code, if you know that you will get the attributes in order from the csv file, and it is not supposed to change, you can just change the instantiation code to:

for line in csv_ff:
    if len(line)==15:
        dd.add_data(*line)

That "*" prepending the line sequence will "unfold" each of its elements in a positional argument to the call to .add_data. - that would remove all the variable names.

You could do the same in the `add_data` method - it can be jsut:

```
def add_data(self, *args):
    self.all_data.append(DATA(*args))
```

The "*" in the function(/method) definition just tells Python to take all remaining positional arguments, and put them in a list with name "args".
We are not using the argumetns there, we just pass them. folded as they are, to the `DATA` object constructor.  Note that this also decouples your TOOLBOX class from the specific attributes for your objects.

There are tricks to also shorten the way `DATA` is implemented, but there would be a trade-off with readability/complexity. (albeit small)

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be a simple solution:

```
class DATA:
def __init__(self,Price):   # skipped other parameters    
    self.Price = Price

class TOOLBOX(object):

def __init__ (self):
    self.alldata = []

def add_data(self, Price):
    self.alldata.append(DATA(Price))

def get_prize(self) :
    price=[]
    for line in self.alldata:
            price.append(line.Price)
    print(price)
    return price

def summation(self):
    return sum(self.get_prize())

# use example
T=TOOLBOX()
T.add_data(2)
T.add_data(3)
print(T.summation())
# 5
```

get_prize() can be written more elegantly:

```
 def get_prize(self) :
    price = [line.Price for line in self.alldata]
    print(price)
    return price
```